# Ruby ArgumentError when actually providing correct arguments

Tags: ruby, email

Ruby complains i am not providing enough arguments to my script, which is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'mail'

def send(file,recipients_csv)
     recipients=recipients_csv.split(",")
      recipients.each do |recipient|
       Mail.defaults do
        delivery_method :smtp,{ :address => 'localhost', :port => 25,:openssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
       end
        mail = Mail.new do
         from 'noreply@mydomain.com'
         to "#{recipient}"
         subject "test"
         body "test"
         add_file :filename => "a_testfile.tsv", :content => File.read(file.path)
        end
       mail.deliver!
      end
end

testfile=File.new("newfile.tsv","w")
send(testfile,"name@mydomain.com")
```

What i get back is:

```
Mailer.rb:4:in `send': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.15/lib/treetop/runtime/compiled_parser.rb:18:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/elements/address_list.rb:26:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `new'
```

I dont get this, the arguments i provide are obviously 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be conflicting with the Ruby base `send` method. Try renaming `send` to `send_mail` (or something), to avoid overwriting the `send` method

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the issue. Honestly i find it quite an uncomfortable 'feature'.

Answer (score 2):

This error isn't coming from when you are running the script yourself on line 22, you are clearly passing it two arguments. It is actually coming from one of the three files you see in your error stack.

```
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.15/lib/treetop/runtime/compiled_parser.rb:18:in `parse'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/elements/address_list.rb:26:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `new'
```

If you go into those files `send` is being called with only one argument as opposed to two.